# Django: request.user in form

Tags: django, django-forms

How may I get the user details to use within a from?  I know in the view I can just do:

`currentUser=request.user`

But if I use it in the form as so I get the following error "'request' is not defined".

```
class SelectTwoTeams(BootstrapForm):

    currentUser=request.user

    date_joined = currentUser.date_joined.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

    timeless30 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3610)
    timeless30 = timeless30.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

    if date_joined > timeless30:
        currentCharities = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Charity.objects.filter(enabled=1), empty_label=None, widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format"}))

    team1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format"}))
    team2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StraightredTeam.objects.none(), empty_label=None,
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class":"select-format"}))
```

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Below shows the **init** of this form just incase it may help.  I know how to get access to the user data using kwargs for this part:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    self.currentSelectedTeam1 = kwargs.pop('currentSelectedTeam1', None)
    self.currentSelectedTeam2 = kwargs.pop('currentSelectedTeam2', None)
    self.currentfixturematchday = kwargs.pop('currentfixturematchday', None)
    self.currentCampaignNo = kwargs.pop('currentCampaignNo', None)
    super(SelectTwoTeams, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.select_related().filter(~Q(fixtureid__fixturematchday=self.currentfixturematchday),campaignno=self.currentCampaignNo, )

    if not cantSelectTeams:
        queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).order_by('teamname')
    else:
        queryset = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).exclude(teamid__in=cantSelectTeams.values_list('teamselectionid', flat=True)).order_by('teamname')

    teamsAlreadyPlaying = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(soccerseason=1025, fixturematchday=self.currentfixturematchday, fixturedate__lte = timezone.now())
    postponedGames = StraightredFixture.objects.filter(soccerseason=1025, fixturematchday=self.currentfixturematchday,fixturestatus = "P")

    queryset = queryset.exclude(teamid__in=teamsAlreadyPlaying.values_list('home_team_id', flat=True)).order_by('teamname')
    queryset = queryset.exclude(teamid__in=teamsAlreadyPlaying.values_list('away_team_id', flat=True)).order_by('teamname')
    queryset = queryset.exclude(teamid__in=postponedGames.values_list('home_team_id', flat=True)).order_by('teamname')
    queryset = queryset.exclude(teamid__in=postponedGames.values_list('away_team_id', flat=True)).order_by('teamname')

    self.fields['team1'].queryset = queryset
    self.fields['team2'].queryset = queryset
    self.fields['team1'].initial = self.currentSelectedTeam1
    self.fields['team2'].initial = self.currentSelectedTeam2

    self.fields['team1'].label = False
    self.fields['team2'].label = False

    date_joined = user.date_joined.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

    timeless30 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3610)
    timeless30 = timeless30.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

    if date_joined > timeless30:
        self.fields['currentCharities'].label = False
```

Comment: Try to send the request, in `form.save(request)` in your view and overwrite the `def save(self, user):` method

Comment: Please can you elaborate? In my view I have:  form = SelectTwoTeams(user=request.user,currentSelectedTeam1=currentSelectedTeam1,currentSelectedTeam2=currentSelectedTeam2,currentfixturematchday=fixturematchday,currentCampaignNo=currentCampaignNo)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The form class is defined when the module is loaded. That means that you can't set `currentUser = request.user`, since you don't have access to the request object yet. You should remove that line from your code.

The correct approach is to override the `__init__` method so that it takes the `user`.  If your field definitions depend on the `user` then you need to move them into the `__init__` method.

```
class SelectTwoTeams(BootstrapForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SelectTwoTeams, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        date_joined = self.user.date_joined.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        timeless30 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3610)
        timeless30 = timeless30.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

        if date_joined > timeless30:
            self.fields['currentCharities'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Charity.objects.filter(enabled=1))
        ...
```

You should only use `None` as the default when popping if the `user` is not required. It is required in your case, since you access `self.user.date_joined` in the `__init__` method. By storing the user as `self.user`, you can access it in other methods if required.

Finally, you need to change your view to pass the user when you instantiate the form.

```
if request.method == "POST"
    form = SelectTwoTeams(request.POST, user=request.user)
    ...
else:
    form = SelectTwoTeams(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I have the view as you have it:             form = SelectTwoTeams(request.POST,user=request.user,currentSelectedTeam1=currentSelectedTeam1,currentSelectedTeam2=currentSelectedTeam2,currentfixturematchday=fixturematchday,currentCampaignNo=currentCampaignNo)
 and I have the form now as you have it yet I still can't access the user outside the init... Any thoughts?

Comment: I have done this but the fields are being declared within the root of the class which does not have access to self.  I appreciate I must be doing something fundamentally wrong and appreciate your time.

Comment: If a field definition depends on the user then you need to move it into the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I just had to move it to __init__.  Thanks to everyone else for helping.

Comment: I may notice that you need to pop `user` from kwargs in `__init__` if you're using `super().__init__` or you'll endup by having a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the save method and send the request there.

viewys.py

```
if request.method == "POST"
   if forms.is_valid():
       form.save(request=request.user)
```

and in your forms.py:

```
def save(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs
    self.currentUser = request.user
    super(SelectTwoTeams, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

To get any variable in forms you must pass as kwarg argument then get-it in **init**

In the Form:

```
class someForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...code...

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):

        self.Name = kwargs.pop('SomeName')
```

in your views:

```
yourform = someForm(request.POST or None, initial={'foo': foo}, SomeName= someVar)
```

Comment: It's usually better to limit dependencies as much as possible, so if what's needed is actually a `user` then just pass an `user`, not the full request (hint: try to write some unittests for the form... you'll find out that it's much easier to only have to pass a `user` instead of a full request <g>).

Comment: Also a bare `except` clause is a very bad idea - only ever catch the most specific exception(s) you expect and are willing and able to deal with (here it should be `except KeyError:`)

Comment: Again, you are right. I copy-it from a specific file where this case is right, but in general. better to avoid.