# Accessing user data in a Django form class

Tags: django, django-forms, request

I have a form for which I'd like to use user data to filter the content of a choicefield.
Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045426/3976696), I added all references to `user` in the `__init__` function of my Form class:

```
class MyChoiceField(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_id = self.user.id
        myobjects = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='',queryset = Myobject.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).exclude(name__isnull=True).filter(Q(person__isnull=True) | Q(person=user_id)).distinct(),empty_label=None)
```

And in the view I call it as:

```
def my_view(request):    
    my_list = MyChoiceField(user = request.user) 
    context = {
                'my_list': my_list,
                }
    return render(request, 'foo/bar.html', context)
```

Debugging the `__init__` part indicates the queryset content is correct, but in the view, my_list contains the following:`<MyChoiceField bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=()>`.
Should I include something in the form class, outside of the `__init__` part for this to work?

Comment: There are a few issues here. You aren't passing `request.POST` to the form, so it doesn't have any data. `MyForm` would be a better name than `MyChoiceField`, which isn't a field. When you use `ModelChoiceField`, `queryset` should return a regular queryset, you shouldn't use `values_list`. Perhaps you want a regular `forms.ChoiceField`, or use `label_from_instance` to customise how [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is displayed.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks a lot, I tried passing `request.POST` and now `my_list`'s bound parameter became `True` (i.e. `<MyChoiceField bound=True, valid=Unknown, fields=()>`). However, the form still isn't displaying on the page. Previously, I had a query that didn't depend on the user (and was therefore outside of the `__init__` part), and the form worked fine. Any further tips/ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: You don't appear to have fixed the issues with the field's `queryset` yet. However, I've spotted another issue. You need to update `self.fields['myfield']`, like in the question you link to. Setting `myfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(...)` won't work.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for spotting that! updating the field as in the previous question solved my problem, and the filtered form is now displayed properly. Regarding your `queryset` comment, actually I found that `ModelChoiceField` works for me even with `values_list`, while when attempting `forms.ChoiceField` it did not. I keep note of your other suggestion to customize the display for later, but for now my main question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class MyChoiceField(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_id = user.id
```

Comment: ha, thank you, that indeed works as well, provided I still use `forms.ModelChoiceField` as in my original post. Would you mind explaining why your solution would be preferable than the original (i.e. `self.user = kwargs.pop('user')`)?