# Validating Entered Data with custom constraints in Django Forms in __init__

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

In my project, the user is entering data in a settings page of the application and it should update the database with the user's settings preference. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045233/django-request-user-in-form/) by Alasdair and how using the `__init__()` will allow to access the user's details. I was wondering if it's possible to return data from `__init__()` so I can validate the entered data before calling the `save()` function in the view? This is what I tried (and did not work). I am open to going about this in a better approach so I appreciate all your suggestions!

**EDIT: ** I am deciding on moving the validation of the data entered by the user in the forms file because when I wrote it in my views, I ended up getting 5 if statements (nested). IMO, and given the situation of this application, moving it to the forms seems to be a cleaner approach. I also considered using the clean_['field'] but I need the `side` variable from the `__init__()` function to do that and I am not sure how to extract that value.

### Forms.py

```
class t_max_form(forms.ModelForm):

    side = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        side = kwargs.pop('side', None)

        super(t_max_form, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        if side == "ms":
            self.fields['hs_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'readonly':True})
            self.fields['ms_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control mb-3'})
        elif side == "hs":
            self.fields['hs_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control'})
            self.fields['ms_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'readonly':True})
        else:
            self.fields['hs_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control'})
            self.fields['ms_max_sessions'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control'})

     
        #Trying to validate the data here
        valid_session_count = settings.objects.first()
        if(side == "ms"):
            input_sessions = self.fields['ms_max_sessions'].widget.attrs['readonly']
            if(input_sessions > valid_session_count.max_sessions):
                self.add_error("ms_max_sessions", "You have entered more than the limit set by the TC. Try again")
         elif(side == "hs"):
             input_sessions = self.cleaned_data['hs_max_sessions']
             if(input_sessions > valid_session_count.max_sessions):
                 self.add_error("hs_max_sessions", "You have entered more than the limit set by the TC. Try again")
         else:
             input_sessions = self.cleaned_data['ms_max_sessions'] + self.cleaned_data['hs_max_sessions']
             if(input_sessions > valid_session_count.max_sessions):
                 self.add_error("hs_max_sessions", "You have entered more than the limit set by the TC. Try again")

        return input_sessions
```

And this is what I was trying in my views

### views.py

```
def t_time_slots(request):
    name = request.user.username
    t = t_info.objects.get(student__user__username = name)
    timeSlots = tutor_time_slot.objects.filter(tutor = tutor).order_by('time') 
    side = decide_side(request.user)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = t_time_slot_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if check_unique_time_slot(request.user, form.cleaned_data['day'], form.cleaned_data['time']):
                timeSlots = form.save(commit=False)
                timeSlots.t = t
                timeSlots.save()
                messages.success(request, "Added Successfully")
                return redirect('TTimeSlot')
            else:
                print("Overlap")
                messages.error(request, "The time slot overlaps with a Current one. Please Change the time and try again.")
                return redirect('TTimeSlot')
    else:
        form = t_time_slot_form()
        
    context = {'timeSlots': timeSlots, 'form': form, 'side':side}
    return render(request, 't/t_time_slot.html', context)
```

Comment: The data in the form is get validated ***not at the time of calling `save()` method, but while calling the `is_valid()` method***.

Comment: Also, I couldn't grab the emotion behind moving the validation into the `__init__()` method, Can you explain what kind of advantage that you are looking forward to achieving?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I updated my question to answer you comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `self.side` in the `__init__` method, then you can access it in the `clean()` or `clean_<field>` methods.

I would avoid putting validation code in the `__init__` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    my_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.side = kwargs.pop('side', None)

        super(t_max_form, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        ...

    def clean_my_field(self):
        my_field = self.cleaned_data['my_field']
        # Use self.side to validate data
        if my_field = self.side:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid")
        return my_field
```

Comment: Is it possible to check two fields in forms? There is a particular value that the user could have in which they can edit the two fields. Calling the `cleaned_data` to the other field when working on a specific field wouldn't work.

Comment: Use `clean` for [fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).